# How to change the default camera using the ngx-scanner-qrcode angular library

Tags: angular, qr-code

I am using the ngx-sanner-qrcode library in a project to scan QRCode, but I am wondering how to change its default camera from front to back camera, for a better user experience.

I was expecting to change the default camera in the configuration as follows:

```
<ngx-scanner-qrcode #action="scanner" [config]="{deviceActive: 1}"> </ngx-scanner-qrcode>
```

Unfortunately, it's not clear what configuration setting will allow me to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

To set a camera, use playDevice(deviceId) method, where
deviceId can be get from

```
@ViewChild(NgxScannerQrcodeComponent)
scanner?: NgxScannerQrcodeComponent;

const devices =  this.scanner.devices.value; // or subscribe

const device = devices.find(f => (/back|trás|rear|traseira|environment|ambiente/gi.test(f.label))) ?? devices.pop(); 

this.scanner?.playDevice(device.deviceId);
```